# I can't add 'null' value in MySQL 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, database

When I try to INSERT values in my database, using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO obra (codInstituicao, codInventariadaPor, dataInventariada,nome,codEstadoConservacao, .......)  values (" . $codInstituicao ."," .  $_SESSION['id']. ", NULL, '" . $nome ."' , '" . $codEstadoConservacao . "', ......)
```

In the beginning of this code, is declared:

```
$codEstadoConservacao = (empty($_POST['estadoconservacao']) ?  "NULL" : $_POST['estadoconservacao']);
```

The TYPE of my tables is InnoDB. When I execute the INSERT, i got this error:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'codEstadoConservacao' at row 1
```

Comment: I have to suggest http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Instead of showing us how you build the query, show us the query just before you run it. That way, we can see exactly what's happening

Comment: Your code is [vulnerable to MySQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/453331).

Answer (score 2):

You're inserting a literal string into the database. Remove the double quotes - e.g. use NULL instead of "NULL".

Also, you're prone to SQL injection with that query. You should use something like [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to bind parameters to your SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Two major problems here.

First, if `$codEstadoConservacao` is `NULL` then it will insert `'NULL'`, as a string, literally the text NULL because of the quotation marks. It is not the same thing as MySQL's `NULL`.

Second, I see you grab this value from `$_POST` and build your SQL Query with it without fearing consequences. You are about to be victim of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) / [Injeção de SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

You have to treat all and any user input accordingly to prevent that, using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), or some escape function such as `mysql_real_escape_string()` / `mysqli_real_escape_string()` etc. Look for the options available to whatever database connection method you are user.

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap your NULL value in quotes:

```
, '" . $codEstadoConservacao . "',
```

should be

```
, " . $codEstadoConservacao . ",
```